# Is there any alternative for Webpart in ASP.NET to create Drag an Drop-able Content, or any mix with Jquery..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, web-parts

I'm currently using the WebPartManager to make my content a drag n drop kinda work using the  " **WebPartManager.DesignDisplayMode** " ,this would make the content drag n dropable , but the alignment of my user controls would not be proper. On other hand have already tried with  " **BrowseDisplayMode** " , bt no drag - drop for it. So wanted to know if there is any combination with the jquery, so that I dont have to re-work on my whole thing. Or is there a way to make the alignment of contents in DesignMode, proper as in the Browse Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use widgets from jQuery - probably this is what you need

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JQuery Ui Draggable and Droppable, there are Demos and code available at he following link.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: I tried using the same , what I wanted is to make my User Controls rearrangeable, an save the state for next time login, jquery won't help I feel.. !! details on Web-Part is required..!!